# how can i chain this two constructors by using ":this()

Tags: c#, .net

i have an assignment to built an room by using two walls w1 , w2
i have done the sets and gets
i have just two constructors first one take width , height , thick from user
the second constructor put the thick = .025f by default.
i don't want to use traditional way to make second constructor 
i want itby using
: this(_w1width,_w1height,0.25f,_w2width,_w2height,0.25f)

**how can i chain this two constructors by ":this()"**

```
public Room(float _w1width, float _w1height, float _w1thick, float _w2width, float _w2height, float _w2thick)
    {
        w1 = new Wall(_w1width, _w1height, _w1thick);
        w2 = new Wall(_w2width, _w2height, _w1thick);

    }
    public Room(float _w1width, float _w1height, float _w1thick,
        float _w2width, float _w2height, float _w2thick)
        : this(_w1width,_w1height,0.25f,_w2width,_w2height,0.25f)
    { }
```

Error   2   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ClassesRelations.Room.Room(float, float, float, float, float, float)' and 'ClassesRelations.Room.Room(float, float, float, float, float, float)'    D:\ITI courses\obb\projects\ClassesRelations\ClassesRelations\Room.cs   56  15  ClassesRelations

> Type 'ClassesRelations.Room' already defines a member called 'Room'
>   with the same parameter types D:..\Room.cs

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include more details of what you want to do

Comment: Do you want to input a List() object to the constructor?

Comment: they have the same signature, so it won't let you declare them that way.

Comment: The error is clear enough. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your use case I think the second constructor should only accept width and height for the cuboid.
 public Room(float _w1width, float _w1height,
        float _w2width, float _w2height)
        : this(_w1width,_w1height,0.25f,_w2width,_w2height,0.25f)
    { }

First 2 constructors/methods with same signature are not allowed.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Function_overloading

Constructor chaining is the process of calling one constructor from another constructor with respect to current object.

[image]

In your code the compiler when invoked with 6 floating type parameters cannot differentiate between which constructor definition to go.